# Using array of protocol in Swift class' generics

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Is there any way to use array of protocol's generic?
For example,

```
/* I want to use protocol like below, 
 * but I can't because protocol is not concrete 
 * so cannot make array of it */
class MyClass<T where T:MyProtocol, T:[MyProtocol]> {
    let result: T
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    init(with: String)
}

class SpecialThing: MyProtocol {
    let appleWatch: AppleWatch

    init(with: String) {
        self.appleWatch = AppleWatch(with)
    }
}

class SampleClass {
    func test {
        typealias listCallback = (MyClass<[SpecialThing]>, NSError) -> ()
        typealias oneCallback = (MyClass<SpecialThing>, NSError) -> ()
    }
}
```

There can be one object or array of protocol's subclass.
I think "typealias" does not help me.

I want to find something more simple way.....

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have the generic type T specified as MyProtocol and array of MyProtocol at the same time.

Comment: I think so. I want to initialize generic object in MyClass. Researched everything but still cannot find solution.

Comment: Not possible far as I know. Pretty obvious but the only "solution" I know is `class MyClass<T where T:MyProtocol> {
    let result: [T]
}`

Comment: @WillGlück I already solved my problem as exactly what you said. Just I was wondering there is another better way to do this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first issue with this is that the type signature is wrong:

```
class MyClass<T where T:MyProtocol, T:[MyProtocol]>
```

That's the same type of thing as doing:

```
let t: String
let t: [String]
t = String("foo")
```

The compiler will complain because you are redefining `T`, once as a `MyProtocol` and again as an array of `MyProtocol`. You can't have both, you can only have one.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Use a construct like `Either`:

```
enum Either<T, U>
{
    case Left(T)
    case Right(U)

    var leftValue: T?
    {
        if case .Left(let leftValue) = self
        {
            return leftValue
        }

        return nil
    }

    var rightValue: U?
    {
        if case .Right(let rightValue) = self
        {
            return rightValue
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Allowing for:

```
class MyClass<T: MyProtocol>
{
    let result: Either<T, [MyProtocol]>
}
```